# Create subdomain - IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, subdomain

Maybe some one can help me understand why i can't create sub domain. My site is working fine for 
*mydomain.com* and *www.mydomain.com*

but when i added *staging.mydomain.com* to the bindings i can't reach to that address for some reason. i read a post here that someone mention the app.config handler setting but i don't know what.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your hosting provider probably has set host names for your site for www.mydomain.com and domain.com, however you would need to ask him to add staging.mydomain.com to the list of host names.

unfortunately IIS does not support wildcard host headers, so you will need to specify the actual host names that you need (that is unless you own the IP address at which point you could just use * which will allow any Host name to be seen there and you could use URL Rewrite to do cool stuff, but owning the IP is rarely the case).

Comment: Thanks Carlos,
I'm running on my own virtual server so i don't have any to ask to do it :)
From iis7 tutorials it should be very straight forward but still it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you add a Binding using the same settings as the others and included the host name you are looking for?

Comment: Yes i have, I can send you a print screen if you like.
I'm really stuck with this problem.